# Change reference level of dummy variable in R

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

If I have a data frame containing columns Width, Length, Colour. With the values in colour - red, blue, green.

I am using the following regression:

```
lm(Width~Length+Colour, df)
```

I would like to change the reference level of the dummy variable to green.

Comment: the programming language is R

Comment: Try using 0, 1, 2 as factor levels instead of red, blue, green. You can also add labels to the numeric factor levels.
Of course, green should be 0.

Comment: How would I add labels?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example (reprex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)